# F# - printfn Guid

Tags: f#

I have following printing example in F#

```
for row in data.Rows do 
     printfn "Example: (%s)" row.A
```

But I received this error

> Script1.fsx(15,67): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have
>   type
>       string     but here has type
>       Guid

I didn't find any example of printing of Guid type.
I tried apply `ToString()` method to `row.A` but it is not working as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `%A` for a Guid, like this:

```
printfn "Example: (%A)" row.A
```

When using `%s`, the type must be a string.

The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx) has more information about which format type to use and how it behaves.

Answer (score 6):

There are two options here:

```
for row in data.Rows do 
     printfn "Example: (%s)" (row.A.ToString())
```

or

```
for row in data.Rows do 
     printfn "Example: (%A)" row.A
```

Here the `%A` can be used for any type and the compiler will automatically print it for you

Comment: Also, a third option: `%O`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers already given, it's worth noting that `Guid` also supports an overload of `ToString`, giving you the option to control how the GUID string is formatted.

You could, for example, write it out like this:

```
printfn "Example: (%s)" (row.A.ToString "n")
```

if you want to omit the hyphens (`Example: (78e6fb89dc5045988d445c4d8aef4e28)`).

Or you could use [`stringf`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/08/stringf) for this, if you want an alternative with pipes instead of parentheses:

```
row.A |> stringf "n" |> printfn "Example: (%s)"
```

or if you don't need the formatting option:

```
row.A |> string |> printfn "Example: (%s)"
```